# want to find the number of times a specific character is in a specific sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Code**

```py
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
character = input("Please enter a single character:")

counter = 0
```

1. using the `while` loop:

```py
while len(character) > 1:
      character = input("Please try again, enter a single character:")
```

2. my problem is that the `if` statements are not working for me.

```py
while len(sentence) > counter:
    if sentence[0].__contains__(character):
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
    if sentence[1].__contains__(character):
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
    if sentence[3].__contains__(character):
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
    if sentence[4].__contains__(character):
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
    if sentence[5].__contains__(character):
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
    if sentence[6].__contains__(character):
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
    if sentence[7].__contains__(character):
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
```

The main problem is if the user enters a sentence greater or less than the amount of 'if statements' the code is not taking

Comment: The main problem is if the user enters a sentence greater or less than the amount of 'if statements' the code is not taking. Maybe there is a complete better way to do it but i cant find any.. quite new to this. sorry if question is not formatted the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without imports, just replace the character in the sentence by an empty string and compare lengths of both sentences :

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
character = input("Please enter a single character:")

counter = len(sentence) - len(sentence.replace(character, ''))
```

To put that in a loop :

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
while 1:
    character = input("Please enter a single character:")
    print(len(sentence) - len(sentence.replace(character, '')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
character = input("Please enter a single character:")

letter_cnts = Counter(sentence)

# Using format
print('Your character {cha} occurs {cnt} times in the sentence'.format(cha=character, cnt=letter_cnts[character]))

# Using f-strings
print(f'Your character "{character}" occurs {letter_cnts[character]} times in the sentence')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use the [count function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=count#str.count)?

In this case the code will be simply like this:

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
character = input("Please enter a single character:")

counter = sentence.count(character)
print(counter)
```

If for any reason, you need to achive this task with a *while* loop, you can try the following code:

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
character = input("Please enter a single character:")

idx = 0
counter = 0
while (idx < len(sentence)):  # loop over the string using idx
    if character == sentence[idx]:  # compare each character of the string with character variable
        counter += 1
    idx += 1

print(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options (some already provided) for implementing a character counter.

Some other pieces to remember:

1. Strings are treated as lists of characters; and with lists you can use the *in* operator to check for membership: i.e. `if character in sentence: [rest of counter code]`
2. Instead of using a `while` loop to iterate over something with a known (or unknown) length, if your *sentence* isn't changing while you're evaluating the number of characters you can (and probably should) use a for loop; which can give you cleaner code without have to explicitly enumerate looking at each character in the *sentence* string

   ```
   input_sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
   input_character = input("Please enter a single character:")

   #<error check of input_caracter - not included here>

   character_counter = 0
   for test_character in input_sentence:
       if input_character == test_character:
           character_counter += 1

   print("Found", character_counter, "Elements of the character", input_character)
   ```

This gives you a basic setup that you could put into a busy-wait `while` loop if the user can input a new character after the first count.  If you need to track the results of any character input, using a counter or default dict would be appropriate in that case (the default dict would be a pigeon-hole counter)

```
from collections import defaultdict

input_sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")

counter_dict = defaultdict(int)
while True:
    input_character = input("Please enter a single character:")

    #<error check of input_caracter - not included here>

    for test_character in input_sentence:
        if input_character == test_character:
            # using a defaultdict allows for you to increment a value without
            # testing for the elements inclusion in the dictionary's keys
            counter_dict[input_character] += 1
```

You could also use the defaultdict to do a count on all of the sentence's letters, and then return back the results with a membership test.

```
from collections import defaultdict

input_sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
input_character = input("Please enter a single character:")

counter_dict = defaultdict(int)
for test_char in input_sentence:
    counter_dict[test_char] += 1

if input_character in counter_dict: # membership tests on dictionaries are against their keys
    print(input_character, ' found ', counter_dict[input_character], ' times')
else:
    print(input_character, ' not found')
```

Short story long: there are a few ways to do counting (others have enumerated some of the ones I haven't), but it really depends on your comfort level with python and your project's requirements.  Based on what you've included, I'd probably make sure I've got the most basic route down (for loop) and understood before even trying something like collections.Counter or collections.defaultdict - since these could cause more confusion if you're already feeling shaky on how to iterate through the string.